# Are these definitions of Exterior Algebra and Clifford Algebra correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

So, I've written some notes on the past year regarding Geometric (Clifford) Algebra. I was revisiting these notes, and I've encountered the following assertion:

"The tensor algebra $T(\mathbf V)$ is the vector space $\mathbf V$
together with the tensor product
$\otimes:\mathbf V \times \mathbf V \to \mathbf V$.
The tensor algebra has the ``free'' algebra flavor,
meaning, it's 'largest' algebra one can construct from $\mathbf V$.
Thus, all other algebras on $\mathbf V$ are quotients of $T(\mathbf V)$,
i.e. we can construct the other bilinear products by introducing equivalence
relations...
One example is the exterior algebra.
To construct it, just impose the following equivalence relation,
for every $\mathbf v \in \mathbf V$,
$$
 \mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v} \cong 0.
$$
Note that this condition implies that
$\mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {u} = - \mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v}$. This follows
from

$$
 (\mathbf u + \mathbf v) \otimes
 (\mathbf u + \mathbf v) =
 \mathbf u \otimes \mathbf u
 +
 \mathbf v \otimes \mathbf v
 +
 \mathbf u \otimes \mathbf v
 +
 \mathbf v \otimes \mathbf u \cong 0.
$$

When considering the exterior algebra, we change the product
notation from $\otimes$ to $\wedge$.

...

Using a similar idea, we arrive at the Geometric (Clifford) Algebra.
Instead of the equality to zero as in the exterior algebra,
we use:

$$
 \mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v} - B(\mathbf v, \mathbf v) \cong 0,
$$
where $B$ is a symmetric bilinear form.
Note that, this definition actually defines a family of algebras (one
for each possible $B$), where the exterior algebra is one of them (just
use $B(x,x) = 0$)."

So, this might sound silly, but I have no idea where I found this construction, or if it came from myself. Thus, I was wondering if this is indeed correct. Also, if it is correct, I'd love a reference where perhaps this topic is presented in this fashion.

Comment: Looks correct to me. The [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) presents the stuff this way and they quote Lang and Bourbaki, so I would look there if you want a textbook account. Btw, no need to put scare quotes around "free", on the contrary, I would put some emphasis on the categorical point of view (universal properties), although of course that is a matter of tastes/objectives.

Comment: Perfectly fine, you should be able to find this in any text with a section on Clifford algebras. Off the top of my head, all these text should have this construction: *Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra* by Grove, *Clifford Algebras and the Classical Groups* by Porteous, *Clifford Algebras and Spinors* by Lounesto, *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelson, and *Orthogonal and Symplectic Clifford Algebras* by Crumeyrolle.

Comment: The constructions that I've seen are more convoluted (probably more rigorous)? For example, they actually define an ideal in order to define the quotient of the tensor algebra.

Comment: @DaviBarreira That's exactly the same thing. Imposing relations is the same as quotienting by the ideal generated by the relations. You even used the word "quotient" in your question; if you don't quotient by an ideal, you don't get an algebra. It is true that all the books I mentioned only talk about quotienting by an ideal, and might not explicitly say anything about relations.

Comment: @DaviBarreira Maybe here is your confusion: You say "impose the following equivalence relation". If we quotient by *exactly* that equivalence relation, then the resulting set won't (necessarily) be an algebra; we have to add more relations to ensure this. For instance, in the case of the exterior algebra $$w\otimes v\otimes v \not\cong 0$$ when $w$ isn't a scalar because we have no relation applicable to $w\otimes v\otimes v$, only $v\otimes v$ *by itself*. Adding in all these extra relations is exactly what we do by using the ideal generated by $\{v\otimes v\;:\; v\in V\}$.